# How to auto specify form value in django form

Tags: django-forms

I am working with Django forms
this is my model

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    gen_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.gen_name
```

this is my form

```
class Genreform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:

        model=Genre
        fields={ 'gen_name','pub_date'}
```

but i want  to manually assign the pub_date (i.e. user dont have to fill that)
so  i did

```
class Genreform(forms.ModelForm):
    pub_date=forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(),initial=timezone.now())
    class Meta:

        model=Genre
        fields={ 'gen_name'}
```

but this is not working

this is my request handler

```
def create_genre(request):
    #pdb.set_trace()
    if request.POST:
        form = Genreform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/playlist/home')
    else:
        form=Genreform()

    args={}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = form
    return render_to_response('playlists/add_gen.html',args)
```

please suggest a way to auto fill pub_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the correct code

```
class Genreform(forms.ModelForm):
pub_date=forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(),initial=timezone.now())
class Meta:

    model=Genre
    fields={ 'gen_name','pub_date'}
```